# Reason for the Output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 int a=5;
 printf("%d"+1,a);
}
```

Output: d.
I didn't get how the output is coming: d ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You passed as first argument of `printf` `"%d"+1`; `"%d"` is actually seen as a `const char *` that points to a memory location where `%d` is stored. As with any pointer, if you increment it by one, the result will point to the following element, which, in this case, will be `d`.

`a` is not used, but this should not be a problem since in general (<s>I don't know if it's standard-mandated</s> **Edit:** yes it is, see bottom) the stack cleanup responsibility for variadic functions is up to the caller (at least, [`cdecl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) does it that way<s>, this however may or may not be UB, I don't know</s>*).

You can see it easier this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=5;
    const char * str="%d";
    printf(str + 1, a);
}
```

```
str ---------+
             |
             V
          +----+----+----+
          |  % |  d | \0 |
          +----+----+----+

str + 1 ----------+
                  |
                  V
          +----+----+----+
          |  % |  d | \0 |
          +----+----+----+
```

Thus, (`"%d"+1`) (which is `"d"`) is interpreted as the format string, and `printf`, not finding any `%`, will simply print it as it is. If you wanted instead to print the value of `a` plus 1, you should have done

```
printf("%d", a+1);
```

---

**Edit:**
* ok, it's not UB, at least for the C99 standard (§7.19.6.1.2) it's ok to have unused parameters in `fprintf`:

> If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are
> evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

and `printf` is defined to have the same behavior at §7.19.6.3.2

> The printf function is equivalent to fprintf with the argument stdout interposed
> before the arguments to printf.

Comment: Thank you :) (random text to reach 15 chars)

Comment: Passing the unused value to printf is required to not be a problem by the standard.  The actual implementation is, of course, allowed to vary, but I've not seen other than as you describe.

Comment: "at least for the C99 standard" -- and the others. It would be horrible if the standard required a varargs function to consume all of its arguments in order for the behavior to be defined.

Comment: @JimBalter: it's definitely been a while since I wrote this answer, but I suppose I wrote that because I didn't have the C89 standard available (as for C11, it didn't exist yet). Feel free to add the relevant quotations from the other versions of the standard.

Answer (score 12):

String literals are pointers. Advancing the pointer to `"%d"` by 1 results in `"d"`. The argument is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

You should do `printf("%d", a+1)`. `"%d" + 1` is a pointer to `"d"` inside an array of `char` (`{'%','d','\0'}`).

Answer (score 1):

Because of `+1`. If you want to increment `a` do: `printf("%d", a + 1);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had:

```
char x[] = "%d";
```

What do you expect

```
printf(x + 1, a);
```

to print?

Hint: t.c:5: warning: too many arguments for format

Answer (score 0):

"%d" is String constant, it will be stored in the char[] in the memory. During runtime, "%d" returns the starting location of the char[]. Increasing character array pointer by one, will point to the next character. Hence "d" alone is passed to the printf function. so the output is "d"