# What would the C code display?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reason for the Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880402/reason-for-the-output)

Hi,

Can you please explain me the output of this code snippet? The answer is "d"

```
void main()
{
short int a=5;
clrscr();
printf("%d"+1,a);
getch();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880402/reason-for-the-output/3880411

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"%d" + 1` is a pointer to `"d"`, so in fact you are executing `printf( "d", a );`.

Answer (score 0):

`"%d"+1` is `"d"`, therefore the output will be `"d"`.

Answer (score 0):

Question a part...

Why didn't the writer simply used:

```
printf("d");
```

Is it the same?

Comment: Well, I thought it'd display "d" without the quotes... :-/

Comment: And the answer to your question is: Because this is a homework assignment where students are supposed to demonstrate that they understand pointers and string literals, and OP wants us to do his homework for him.

Comment: I don't understand why he used the character "%" though, and what does the "a" parameter does exactly?